# Error printing a string

Tags: c, search, printf, frequency

I'm creating a algorithm that generate numbers (numbers like strings) from 0 to 9999 and search its frequency in a array a[50000].

```
  char key[4];
  int freq;
  for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    sprintf(key,"%04i",i); // save 4 digits in key, if i <1000 save leading 0's
    freq = BruteForceStringMatch(key,a,n); //n length of a.
    printf("%s-%i\n",key,freq);
  }
  free(a);
```

but, when I run the program, I get it.

```
.
.
.
9845-7
9846
-10
9847-4
9848-5
-139
9850-3
9851-6
9852-5
9853-4
9854-2
9855-7
9856-5
9857-4
9858-5
9859    -9
9860-3

.
.
.
9968-6
9969    -9
9970-5
9971-4
9972-7
9973-6
9974-6
9975-2
9976-7
9977-4
9978-2
9979-7
9980-3
9981-4
9982-3
9983    -9
9984-6
9985-7
998-8
9987    -9
9988-3
9989    -9
9990-4
9991-3
9992-5
9993-2
9994    -9
9995-5
9996-6
9997-7
9998-7
```

There are tabs in randoms position,sometimes the last digit of key is eliminated and there are 139,113,etc that I have no idea where they come from. I'm using gcc version 5.4.0 (GCC) and compile it with windows 10 and the terminal babun.

More information:

BruteForceStringMatch search the frequency of key in a.

```
int BruteForceStringMatch(char key[4], char* a, int length ){
  int freq=0;
  int k;
  for (int j = 0; j < length -4; j++) { 
    k =0;
    while(k <4 && key[k] == a[j+k])
      k=k+1;
    if(k == 4) 
        freq++;
  }
  return freq;
}
```

I get a from a file with 5000 digits.

```
FILE *inputfile;
  char c;
  int largo = 0;
  char *a = (char *)malloc(50000*sizeof(char *));;
  char *b = (char *)malloc(50000*sizeof(char *));;
  inputfile = fopen("archivo_1.tex", "r");
  if (inputfile == NULL) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open the file.\n");
      exit(1);
  }
  if (inputfile) {
      for ( int i=0; (c = getc(inputfile)) != EOF; i++){
          a[i] = c;
          //putchar(a[i]);
          largo++;
      }
      fclose(inputfile);
  }
```

Comment: We need enough code to replicate the problem.

Comment: Can you also post the definition of `BruteForceStringMatch` ?

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: You're using `char key[4]` and try to assign 4 characters to that array. You're leaving no room for the end of string character. Increase your char array size to 5

Comment: Thanks Rogus,  change key[4] to key[5] works!.

Comment: Also remember to delete the allocated memory. In your `if (inputfile == NULL)` you should call `free(a);`  and `free(b);` before exiting.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me your problem is that you defined "key" to only be four chars, when it should be five -- four digits *plus* the terminating null.  So that null ends up in the first byte of "freq"... then when you set "freq" in line 5, that value gets seen by printf (on line 6) as part of the "key" string.  In particular, you can see this in the output for the values 9859 and 8859, where the value of "freq" happens to be 9, which is the ASCII code for a tab.  Also, for value 9846 and "freq" is 10, which happens to be the ASCII value for linefeed (i.e., newline), and on 9849, where "freq" is 13, which is a carriage return, so "-13" prints over the first three characters of 9849.